# Why are there many queues with longValue or number being created in Artemis console?

Tags: activemq-artemis

While I am creating the queue or topic in ActiveMQ Artemis the web console is showing me more long valued or number valued queue or topic respectively.

- Why are they being created?
- How to make sure they are not created?
- What is their purpose?

Comment: How are you creating these queues & topics? Can you share a screenshot of the console to demonstrate the "long valued or number valued" names?